# How to get a list to correctly count the total number of int in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2010, arraylist

I know I must be doing something wrong however, after banging my head against it for 8 hours I just cant seem to spot where I'm going wrong.

I have 2 gameobjects "Block1", "Block2". I want to be able to count the total blocks when they enter the circle. To do so I did the following:

Put a script on each block called NumberBlock. I then convert the block to its Integer using the below script:
 public int number;
     string str;

```
private void Awake()
{
    str = gameObject.transform.name; //first get the name

    str = str.Substring(str.Length -1, 1); //remove all words apart from number
    int.TryParse(str, out number); //convert string to number


}
```

This successfully leaves me with int number = 1, 2 etc.

I then push the block into the sphere. The sphere has a script that does the following:
1- Creates an empty list of intergers
2- OnTriggerEnter Checks the objects tag is not the player or the ground
3-  Gets the objects Numberblock Script and checks the blocks "IntNumber", then adds it to InCircle list. Finally a foreach sums each number to give a total (TotalBlocks).

//keep track of how many numbers in circle
    public List InCircle = new List();

```
//add the total number in the blocks
public int BlockNumber;
public int TotalBLocks;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{

    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (other.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        return;
    }

    //get the blocks number
    BlockNumber = other.transform.GetComponent<Numberblocks>().number;

      //add block number to the list
      InCircle.Add(BlockNumber);

    foreach (int e in InCircle)
    {
        TotalBLocks += e;

    }

}
```

The issue as seen in the screenshot is the TotalBlocks sums the values incorrectly. Block 1 & block 2 should sum 3 not 4. The InCircle list stores the 2 values correctly, I also verified by storing the gameobjects which also displays correctly.

Please help me see where I am doing this wrong?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GCpx.png)

Comment: I would also watch out for that method of getting the number if you ever have more than 9 blocks it will stop working (as there will be more than one digit in the number)

Comment: Yeah I did notice that would be an issue, fortunately for the game I dont think it will be an issue however, its more for a proof of concept phase as my coding skills are a joke!

Answer (score 1):

```
TotalBLocks += e;
```

is also executed the first time for `Block1` so it has already `1` when you come to the next call with now `Block1` and `Block2` => `1 + 1 + 2 = 4`

---

You would either want to reset it before recalculating:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (other.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        return;
    }

    BlockNumber = other.transform.GetComponent<Numberblocks>().number;

    InCircle.Add(BlockNumber);

    // Reset this!
    TotalBlocks = 0;
    foreach (int e in InCircle)
    {
        TotalBLocks += e;
    }
}
```

Or simply not use a loop but only add the new block number:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (other.CompareTag("Floor"))
    {
        return;
    }

    BlockNumber = other.transform.GetComponent<Numberblocks>().number;

    // Not sure if still needed then
    InCircle.Add(BlockNumber);

    // Only add the new number
    TotalBLocks += BlockNumber;
}
```

---

I would also add a HashSet for making sure each object is only added once to the list to avoid duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks this solved it! Didnt know it would be so easy *sigh*. Thanks for the advice on Hashsets, will investigate that for optimisations.